# Call method of all chlidren items in a list of React PureComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React. I have a list component that is composed of an array of editable items and I wanted to use Pure Components for the item component.
I want to serialize the whole list calling a *serialize* method in every item of the list whitch returns an object.

Something like:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const items = [
      { name: 'first' },
      { name: 'second' }
    ];

    const itemComponents = items.map((elem, index) => {
      return <Item
        key={index}
        name={elem.name}></Item>
    });

    return <div>
      {itemComponents}
      <button onClick={this.serialize}>Serialize</button>
    </div>
  }

  serialize() {
    console.log(); //todo: serialized list??
  }
}

class Item extends React.PureComponent<{ name: string }, { checked: boolean }> {
  constructor(props: { name: string }) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { checked: false }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onChange={() => this.setState(prevState => ({ checked: !prevState.checked }))} />
    </div>
  }

  // cannot be accessed from parent
  serialize() {
    return {
      name: this.props.name,
      checked: this.state.checked
    }
  }
}
```

Looking around I found that a solution may be to 'lift the state' and have the event handling of the items defined in the List component. That may be fine in this example but my actual items are more complex and I wanted to avoid having one massive component.
Another solution that may be possible uses the *useRef()* hook but I get a compilation error with the PureComponent and defies the purpose of using them. As far as I am concerned the Item component is Pure since does not have side effects.

Am I missing something? Should I be doing things completely differently?

Comment: What is the purpose of this serialization?

Comment: This is a list of items. I want to have a List component that has many Item components inside and a button. The button will serialize the content and send a HTTP request.
I managed to hack around the problem by having the state of every item duplicated into an array stored in the parent state. I don't think this is a good solution since it's convoluted and introduces side effects in the Item components but I'm willing to publish it if someone needs it

Comment: If you already have a state in the parent component, why would you have it also in the children?

Comment: That's part of the question, should I do things differently? I did things this way mainly for simplicity and and reusability. If the children manages its own state I can swap the parent. It does make sense to me that the child is as independent as possible from the parent

Comment: This is not always a good thing. Read about [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) components.
Controlled components are usually used with forms you are trying to do.